# Multiple Categorical Relative Frequency Bar PLot

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I want to plot multiple frequency relative proportion bar plots. Here are my categories: hsdrunk, drunk, housing. It looks something like this：

```
housing： 1， 2， 3， 1， 4， 3， 1， 2
drunk: 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1
hsdrunk： 1， 0， 0， 1， 0， 0， 1， 1
```

I want to plot the proportional frequency of drunk by housing category, but also separated by value of hsdrunk (1 or 0).

I have been able to create something where it is proportional by housing category, but am not sure how to add additional category of "hsdrunk”。

```
png("Graphs/Analysis_Figure1.png")

analysis %>%  

 count(housing, drunk) %>% 

group_by(housing) %>% 

 mutate(freq = n/sum(n)) %>% 

 filter(drunk == 1) %>%

ggplot(aes(x = housing, y = freq, fill = drunk)) + 

geom_bar(stat="identity", position = 'dodge')

dev.off()
```

Here is my desired output:

[image: Desired Output]

This is my result so far:

[image: Actual Output]

Comment: Welcome to contributing to StackOverflow! Can you provide your data or a sample of it, to make a reproducible example (e.g. using `dput`)? That makes it far easier to help you out. As it is I can't quite figure out where some of your variables are coming from, like `volfree`, given the data you started with.

Comment: I made a small mistake, volfree should be housing!

Comment: Thanks! What about the fact that all of your variables at the top are numeric and binary (perhaps factor levels), but your filter has `drunk == "3 or More"`? What does `3 or More` map to, just so that I can follow along with your example?

Comment: “3 or more” is the label attached to drunk==1, and "2 or Fewer" is label for drunk==0.

Comment: FYI I've edited my answer and it should get you what you need now.

Comment: did you ever find the answer you need?

Comment: I did! Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I really don't think you want to be using `position = "dodge"` for this. You'll have troubles with bar width and spacing and even labeling. What's made for this in `ggplot2` is `facet_grid()`. Then most of the magic of making it look the way you want it actually happens in `theme()`.

I walk through a full solution below. I really want you to have a sense here of the way `ggplot2` was *built* to handle this (using facets and theme elements). In the Grammar of Graphics, this way of thinking is meant to flow very naturally.

I built it out to the *extent* that I did to give you some inspiration of just *how* it can be done with `theme()`. Otherwise, frankly, how else can you be sure I'm pointing you in the right direction? The theme elements, and the rest of `ggplot2`, get more intuitive with use. Here's to many more hours of practice.

---

Here's the data you provided. I added keys to your factor levels as named vectors (guessing re: what means what, based on plot positioning). You'll notice I already baked in some line breaks (`\n`) to the housing levels to make the plotting easy and nice.

```r
library(tidyverse)

analysis <- tribble(
  ~housing, ~drunk, ~hsdrunk,
         1,      1,        1,
         2,      0,        0,
         3,      1,        0,
         1,      0,        1,
         4,      0,        0,
         3,      0,        0,
         1,      0,        1,
         2,      1,        1
)
housing_levels <- c(
      `1` = "Not\nAlc.-Free",
      `2` = "Assigned"      ,
      `3` = "All\nAlc.-Free",
      `4` = "Requested"
)
hsdrunk_levels <- c(
      `0` = "Low HS Drinking",
      `1` = "High HS Drinking"
)
```

This is a minor tweak, but your y-axis labels are pretty specific: 0 is expressed as "0," and decimals have no leading 0s. You can do this with a custom function like this one:

```r
label_y <- function(y) {
  y <- scales::number(y, accuracy = .1)
  y[y == "0.0"] <- "0"
  sub("0.", ".", y, fixed = TRUE)
}
```

I set your bar color (why not) and I even took a look at your plot background color. There are nuances I wanted to make you aware of when you're specifying a background color. (See the `theme()` section below.)

```r
darkslategrey <- "#1a476f"
whitesmoke <- "#eaf2f3"
```

All right, let's get down to business.

- `recode_factor()` is a vectorized `switch()` function; it magically turns those numbers into the actual character values you want plotted. You probably won't need this with your base data, but it was useful for me. **Of note** here is the fact that *the order of your factor levels* determines the order on the page. By using `recode_factor()` instead of `recode`, I'm asserting the order I set in my named vectors.
- Then I `group_by()` high school drinking and housing. Since `drunk` is encoded as 1s and 0s, it's really easy to get the proportion; just use `mean(drunk)` (not that there are any mean drunks here).
- In the call to `facet_grid()`, I use `switch = "x"` to "switch" the label position from the top to the bottom.
- You can tweak the distance between `housing` levels using the `width` argument of `geom_bar()`, and the distance between `hsdrunk` groups using the call to `expand_scale()` in `scale_x_discrete()`. `expand_scale()` is a pretty cool function; check out the docs for [`expand_*_continuous()`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_continuous.html) and [`expand_scale()`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/expand_scale.html) to learn more. You could also use a theme element, `panel.spacing`, to separate your groups. But you're prevented from doing that by reasons I explain below.
- You'll see minor tweaks in the `scale_y_continuous()` statement, setting the breaks and labels the way they show up in your "desired" plot.
- I also added the caption, and here you'll note that I'm not sure there's a sure-fire way to align it the way it's aligned in your visual. As a kludge, it does work to add a bunch of spaces till it looks right.

Like I say, most of the magic happens in the `theme()` call. There are numerous ways to do this, including starting with another base theme and adding from there. All these options are documented thoroughly in the `theme()` [docs](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/theme.html), but it wouldn't be much of an answer if I just told you to read the docs, would it? I encourage you to run this code without any of the `theme()` arguments, and then add them one by one and see what they do. Here's a walk-through:

- `strip.placement` and `strip.background` place the `hsdrunk` labels outside the x-axis with a transparent background.
- The *plot* is the whole visual, everything that goes in your `png`. A plot can have 1 or more *panels* for data visualization; in your case there are two. `plot.background` and `panel.background` set the background colors for each.
- But then you're left with a problem. (**Note**: *This is the nuance I mentioned* about background colors...) The two white panels are separated, and since the plot background is a different color the separation is really obvious. To make it look like your "desired" plot, set `panel.spacing` to 0 so they make a single, seamless, white area. Of course that also puts your groups right next to each other, but we already addressed that using `expand_scale()`.
- You still don't have any panel gridlines, though, because the base grid is white. So set `panel.grid.major.y` to that same whitesmoke color you used for the plot background.
- `axis.line` gets you that black line at the x- and y-axes. You might be tempted to use `panel.border` for this, but `panel.border` would put lines at the top, on the right, and even between the panels.
- Your y-axis labels are turned sideways! So you need to change their `angle` to 90°. `hjust = .5` centers them at the tick marks.
- Speaking of tick marks, the x-axis in your final plot doesn't have them. So you'll need to use `axis.ticks.x` to remove them. You can remove the x-axis title the same way.
- Lastly, you have your caption over on the left, which is accomplished with an `hjust` (horizontal justification) of 0.

```r
analysis %>% 
  mutate(
    housing = recode_factor(housing, !!!housing_levels),
    hsdrunk = recode_factor(hsdrunk, !!!hsdrunk_levels)
  ) %>% 
  group_by(hsdrunk, housing) %>% 
  summarise(drunk = mean(drunk, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = housing, y = drunk)) +
  facet_grid(cols = vars(hsdrunk), switch = "x") +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = darkslategrey, width = .7) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = expand_scale(add = 1)) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    name   = "Proportion drunk 3 or more times in past 30 days",
    breaks = function(limits) seq(limits[1], limits[2], by = .2),
    labels = label_y,
    expand = expand_scale(mult = c(0, .05))
  ) +
  labs(caption = paste0(
      "Figure 6: Students in All Housing Types\n",
      "                 Controlling for HS Drinking"
  )) +
  theme(
    strip.placement    = "outside",
    strip.background   = element_blank(),
    plot.background    = element_rect(fill = whitesmoke),
    panel.background   = element_rect(fill = "white"),
    panel.spacing      = unit(0, "lines"),
    panel.grid.major.y = element_line(color = whitesmoke),
    axis.line          = element_line(color = "black"),
    axis.text.y        = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = .5),
    axis.ticks.x       = element_blank(),
    axis.title.x       = element_blank(),
    plot.caption       = element_text(hjust = 0)
  )
```

[image]

You may not need to do all this wrangling, depending how literal you're trying to be with this desired plot. In particular, you can make it easier on yourself if you drop the background color, and if your factors are already present in your data and ordered properly. But I wanted you to have all the tools you needed to reach your stated goal with the data and parameters you presented. Happy coding!